# Null value check in case of Set<String>

Tags: apex, salesforce1-app, set, collection

I am using a

`set < string > queue = new set < string > ();`

I am using an if to filter out null values

`if(queue.size() > 0 && !queue.isEmpty())`

`{ system.debug('queue '+queueaddress); }`

In logs I can see that queue is {null}
But still it is going inside the if condition .
Please advise how to do a null check here

Thanks in advance

Comment: Both the IF conditions return false, so there is no way that execution would enter the IF loop.

Comment: Are you trying to avoid adding a null entry to the set, or to detect that the set contains a null value? Or are you trying to detect a null set?

Comment: I think your `queue` Set might be containing null value. The only way to avoid it to iterate and skip the null value from `Set`. Or best is to not add null to set.

Answer (score 1):

The only way it will go inside if condition is when your `Set` has null as a value inside it.

The only way to avoid it to remove it via `queue.remove(null);` or iterate and skip the null value from Set Or best is to not add null to set.

Comment: I prefer removing null afterwards instead of an if statement inside the loop, because you only end up running the remove(null) once instead of hundreds or thousands of if statements being executed.

Comment: Thanks @sfdcfox for your inputs, I prefer to not add nulls by checking it earlier.

Comment: That's fine. It's only ~10% more CPU time to do it that way. Just saying that if you need performance gains, this is an easy one to utilize.

Comment: Thanks, as usual, for your valuable inputs @sfdcfox